# saving multiple value options from a form that uses the select tag in Angular 4

Tags: angular, forms, html-select

I have a form in an Angular 4 project that, after being submitted, creates a user.  I managed to get all of my form values that were generated in input-fields to attach to the user but I am not sure of how to capture the values within a multiple select... My code below shows what I have within my **user-new.component.html**.  I am not sure which part of a Select receives the ngModel but am guessing the option would need to communicate with the select tag... I am not sure though...  I am using materialize css though and my select tag is working exactly like the one in the link just below.  The options get saved from what I see but I know they are not being associated with my user as I haven't done anything to connect them.

Here's my html that needs maybe ids for all of the options. Again, all input fields linking and the materialzie css page I am using as reference
http://materializecss.com/forms.html

```
<h4>UserNewComponent</h4>
<div class="row">
  <form materialize class="col s12" (submit)="create()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="newUser.username">
        <label for="username">USERNAME?</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <textarea id="textarea1" name="motto" class="materialize-textarea" [(ngModel)]="newUser.motto"></textarea>
        <label for="textarea1">YOUR MOTTO. THE REASON YOU ARE HERE?</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <select multiple>
        <option value="" disabled selected>GENRES THAT YOU FANCY</option>
        <option value="acoustic">ACOUSTIC</option>
        <option value="alternative_rock">ALTERNATIVE ROCK</option>
        <option value="blues">BLUES</option>
        <option value="classic_rock">CLASSIC ROCK</option>
        <option value="classical">CLASSICAL</option>
        <option value="comedy">COMEDY</option>
        <option value="country">COUNTRY</option>
        <option value="electronic">ELECTRONIC</option>
        <option value="experiemntal">EXPERIMENTAL</option>
        <option value="jazz">JAZZ</option>
        <option value="metal">METAL</option>
        <option value="pop">POP</option>
        <option value="raggae">RAGGAE</option>
        <option value="rap">RAP</option>
        <option value="rock">ROCK</option>
        <option value="r_and_b">R&B</option>
      </select>
      <label for="genres">GENRE(S)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="newUser.password">
          <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="newUser.confirmPassword">
    <label for="confirmPassword">CONFIRM THIS</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" class="waves-effect waves btn-large red col s12">
  </form>
</div>
```

This is my Angular 4 user.ts

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public _id: number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100),
        public username = "",
        public motto: string = "",
        public genres:string[] = [],
        public password: string = "",
        public confirmPassword: string = "",
        public editable: boolean = false  
    ){}
}
```

Should I be adding the options to the genres arrary I am creating?

Finally, here's my **user-new.component.ts**

```
import { User } from "./../user";
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-new',
  templateUrl: './user-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-new.component.css']
})
export class UserNewComponent implements OnInit {
  newUser = new User();
  @Output() createNewUserEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  create(){
    // call server to save
    this.createNewUserEvent.emit(this.newUser);
    this.newUser = new User();
  }

}
```

Comment: I think I'll run into the same problem.  What are you suggesting?  How will this interact with materialize?  I'm not trying to just bounce from attempting solution to solution.  I feel like I'm almost there going the route I'm going. Maybe a reason why to use that route?  I feel like I'm close using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `ngModel` to your select field and it should work. I tried it at https://angular-smhjoc.stackblitz.io

```
public selectedFields: string[] = [];
```

Inside HTML

```
<select multiple ([ngModel])="selectedFields" >
```

Upon selecting, `selectedFields` will have an array of strings selected

Comment: thank you.  I think I'm close.  Are you saying to put the `public selectedFields: string[] = [];'` inside my **user.ts** file?  That adds an empty array to my user called selectedFields...  But isn't that what my `public genres:string[] = [],` is already there for?  I'm not seeing, I guess, how the values of the select options are being linked to any output.  I would imagine from what you've suggested and what my other `ngModel`'s look like, that my select field should look like this: `<select multiple materialize="material_select" [(ngModel)]="newUser.genres">` ... is that correct?

Comment: My options tags only have a value... I also am realizing that if I want to show these values again in a user profile, I should probably be saving them in my new-user.component.ts file correct?

Comment: When user selects the values, those values are included in the user profile. From there you can send them to a service or do http call its upto you

Comment: awesome.  I get it.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: rats... after submitting user info, I am using `<div *ngFor="let user of users"> {{ user.username }} - {{ user.motto }} - {{ user.genres }} </div>` to to display the info submitted on the same page.  I am still getting an empty array after making my changes.  Don't I need to be pushing some aspect of the follwoing code to the genres array? `<option value="rock" selected>ROCK</option>`

Comment: I added an id and name to the select tag and now it is working! thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Linking to the Github issue: https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/351